# How to convert a list containing formulae into a sequence of model formulae

Tags: r, r-formula

The DAG(...) function in the ggm package takes arguments that are a sequence of model formulae separated by commas. For instance:
DAG(x~y, y~z)
I have a list containing formulae.  For instance, it might be:

```
library(ggm)

fo<-list(x~y,y~z)
> fo
[[1]]
x ~ y

[[2]]
y ~ z
```

However, I cannot pass this list to the DAG() function because it expects a sequence of formulae (see above).

Question:  How can I convert this list into a sequence of formulae?  Note that this will be done inside of a function and the number of formulae in the list will vary from call to call.

Comment: Does `do.call(DAG, args = fo)` work?

Comment: @I_O post it as an answer! :-) I'll upvote

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of doing it:

```
library(purrr)

x <- 1:10
y <- 21:30
z <- 31:40
fo<-list(x~y,y~z)

map(fo, DAG)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `do.call(DAG, args = fo)`.

`do.call` calls a function, with the desired arguments supplied as a list - which you conveniently already have.